# Select and update table columns without ID in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to make page in admin panel from where the admin can change site settings such as: `site title`, `default country` etc.

I've created table in database called `settings` without ID because I don't really need it. It will be only one row which will be updated. No inserts of new rows.

I have add this lines in my route.php

```
Route::get('settings', 'SettingsController@index')->name('admin.settings');
Route::post('settings/update', 'SettingsController@update')->name('admin.settings.update');
```

This is my update function in SettingsController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $settings = Settings::all();
    return view('backend.settings',compact('settings'));
}
public function update( Request $request)
{

    $settings->settings_site_title = $request['site_title'];
    $settings->settings_item_per_page = $request['item_per_page'];
    $settings->settings_default_country = $request['default_country'];
    $settings->settings_max_image_post = $request['max_image_post'];
    $settings->save();

    return redirect()->route('admin.settings')->with('alert-success', ' Success');
}
```

and the form

```
 @foreach ($settings as $preferences)
     {!! Form::open(['route' => 'admin.settings.update','files' => true , 'class' =>'form-horizontal']) !!}

              <div class="form-group">
                 {!! Form::label('site_title', 'Site Name', array('class'=> 'col-sm-2 control-label')) !!}
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                   {!! Form::text('site_title', $preferences->settings_site_title, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Enter site name', 'id'=>'site_title']) !!}
                  </div>
                </div>

      ... some more inputs like ^

     {!! Form::close() !!}
 @endforeach
```

When I submit the form I've got this error:

> Creating default object from empty value

Update: Model

```
class Settings extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'settings';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'settings_site_title',
        'settings_item_per_page',
        'settings_default_country',
        'settings_max_image_post',
    ];

}
```

Controller

```
public function update( Request $request)
{
    $settings = Settings::first(); //missed line
    $settings->settings_site_title = $request['site_title'];
    $settings->settings_item_per_page = $request['item_per_page'];
    $settings->settings_default_country = $request['default_country'];
    $settings->settings_max_image_post = $request['max_image_post'];
    $settings->save();

    return redirect()->route('admin.settings')->with('alert-success', ' Success');
}
```

Comment: how can you update without id? then try to match some column like site title then get id and then save

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgot to set `$settings` variable in `update` method

```
public function update( Request $request)
{
    $settings = Settings::first(); //missed line
    $settings->settings_site_title = $request['site_title'];
    $settings->settings_item_per_page = $request['item_per_page'];
    $settings->settings_default_country = $request['default_country'];
    $settings->settings_max_image_post = $request['max_image_post'];
    $settings->save();

    return redirect()->route('admin.settings')->with('alert-success', ' Success');
}
```

or even better and shorter

```
public function update( Request $request)
{
    $settings = Settings::first()->update($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('admin.settings')->with('alert-success', ' Success');
}
```

of course this will work only if you fill `fillable` property of `Settings`model with columns you need to mass assign.

```
class Settings extends Model
{
    // ...
    protected $fillable = [
        'site_title',
        'item_per_page',
        'default_country',
        'max_image_post',
    ];
    // ...
}
```

> Edit

Try this

```
public function update( Request $request)
{
    $settings = Settings::first(); //missed line
    $settings->settings_site_title = $request->input('site_title');
    $settings->settings_item_per_page = $request->input('item_per_page');
    $settings->settings_default_country = $request->input('default_country');
    $settings->settings_max_image_post = $request->input('max_image_post');
    $settings->save();

    return redirect()->route('admin.settings')->with('alert-success', ' Success');
}
```

> Edit

add this to your `Settings` model

```
protected $primaryKey = null;
public $incrementing = false;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I like the second shorter variant but it doesn't update the DB. Just reloading the page. What can be the problem here? I have `fillable` properties in Settings model

Comment: With first variant I've got sql error: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: This appears because of your column's name `settings_default_country` and etc in your db, you should add `settings_` prefix to you input names and in fillable names/

Comment: I've added my Model and current controller to the question above. All column names are correct.

Comment: Thanks but still complaining about `ID`. Seems like there is no way to update it without adding ID to the table

Comment: I just saw this and tried it but I've got `error 500`

Comment: Anyway. Thanks for the help and for the short syntax. I should add ID in that table even I don't want.

Comment: Note: setting `$primaryKey = null` then calling `save()` or `update` will be applied to all rows in the table

Answer (score 0):

```
if(count($settings)>0){

}
```

Use this if condition before foreach. I think the $setting variable is empty.

Comment: No, it's not empty because I see all current settings from DB on the page.